# Warning: cmd -> barbar: head not inside head cluster cluster_0

Tags: graphviz

I understood that in graphviz if I set `compound` to `true` I'm able to connect one component with a subgraph instead of it's first element.

my code is this:

```
compound=true;
cmd[shape=component,label="foo"];
barbar[label="bar"];
msg[label="msg"];


subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        msg;
        label = "Instance.alertInstanceBingoChange()";
    }

cmd->barbar->msg[lhead=cluster_0];
```

[image: result]

so as you can see it provides the exact result that I wanted, besides that warning that `barbar: head not inside head cluster cluster_0`

how do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  The change you need to make is a simple one.  Just separate the last statement into two:

```
digraph test {
compound=true;
cmd[shape=component,label="foo"];
barbar[label="bar"];
msg[label="msg"];

subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        msg;
        label = "Instance.alertInstanceBingoChange()";
    }

cmd->barbar;
barbar->msg[lhead=cluster_0];
}
```

Now, I don't know *why* this makes the difference, but it's just one of the peculiarities of DOT.  The above syntax produces no warnings.  Hope this helps you :)